# React hook form v7 Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ref

Getting the error in browser `Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()`

[image]

My code:

```js
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { SubmitHandler, useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import { contactSchema } from 'schemas/schemas'
import { InputFloatLabel } from './components/Inputs/InputFloatLabel'

type TypeFormInput = {
  name: string
  email: string
  textarea: string
}

export const Register = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<TypeFormInput>({ resolver: yupResolver(contactSchema) })

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<TypeFormInput> = async ({ name, email }) => {
    console.log(' ~ file: Register.tsx ~ line 25 ~ email', email)
    console.log(' ~ file: Register.tsx ~ line 25 ~ name', name)
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div>
          <InputFloatLabel
            type="text"
            placeholder="Name"
            {...register('name')}
          />

          <button type="submit">{isLoading ? 'Loading' : 'Send Mail'}</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And the Input comp:

```js
import { useState } from 'react'

type typeInput = {
  placeholder: string
  type?: string
}

export const InputFloatLabel: React.FC<typeInput> = ({ type, placeholder, ...props }) => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false)

  const handleTextChange = (text: string) => {
    if (text !== '') setIsActive(true)
    else setIsActive(false)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        {...props}
        id={placeholder}
        type={placeholder ? placeholder : 'text'}
        onChange={(e) => handleTextChange(e.target.value)}
      />
      <label htmlFor={placeholder}>
        {placeholder ? placeholder : 'Placeholder'}
      </label>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I don't have this issue with ChakraUI that I've built but now just doing plain input as a separate component getting that issue.

I have tried some suggestions from here, but still can't fix it: https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/85

Comment: Did you found any solution or workaround? https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/2120#issuecomment-586200394 . Here is the solution https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/85#issuecomment-502341193

Comment: My workaround was to switch to Mantine's useForm hook. I don't know how the libraries compare to each other, but it was a perfect solution for me.

Answer (score 27):

So the issue is that I think that the `{...register("name"}}` line actually includes a ref property. You could console.log that out to verify; this is what I found to be true when using `{...field}` with the ControlledComponent. A very quick fix to get rid of the console error is to just, after the line with the spread, to add a `ref={null}` to override this ref that is being passed in from the library.

Comment: doesn't the library need that ref to work properly?

Comment: I could be wrong but from my understanding, if you are seeing this error it means that the ref is not properly being passed to the component, so adding the `ref={null}` really just gets rid of the error. If you aren't seeing the error then you shouldn't apply this change.

Comment: I actually encapsulated my custom input FC with a forwardRef to get the ref as is. And It works like a charm. I haven't tried making it null. I think it would disassociate it with the useForm. I'm not sure either.

Comment: @aryankarim you're 100% right!

Answer (score 17):

You forgot to forward the ref in your InputFloatLabel. See https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

In your case it would look like this:

```
export const InputFloatLabel: React.FC<typeInput> =
    // Use React.forwardRef
    React.forwardRef(({type, placeholder, ...props}, ref) => {
      const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false)

      const handleTextChange = (text: string) => {
        if (text !== '') setIsActive(true)
        else setIsActive(false)
      }

      return (
        <div>
          <input
            ref={ref /* Pass ref */}
            {...props}
            id={placeholder}
            type={placeholder ? placeholder : 'text'}
            onChange={(e) => handleTextChange(e.target.value)}
          />
          <label htmlFor={placeholder}>
            {placeholder ? placeholder : 'Placeholder'}
          </label>
        </div>
      )
    })
```

Comment: For anyone using Typescript, use `React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, Props>` instead.

Answer (score 8):

In https://react-hook-form.com/faqs, scroll to "How to share ref usage?" may help?

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const firstNameRef = useRef(null);
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);
  const { ref, ...rest } = register('firstName');

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input {...rest} name="firstName" ref={(e) => {
        ref(e)
        firstNameRef.current = e // you can still assign to ref
      }} />

      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the *field* element and *register* function pass a ref to the element. If you define a custom React Component and try to use it within a controller or with register, funky things can happen. I found using React.forwardRef() solves the problem when using Custom Components.

CustomSwitchComponent.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {FormControlLabel, Switch, SxProps, Theme} from "@mui/material";

const TradingStrategyEditFormInstructionsInputSwitch:
    // Note this type allows us to do React.forwardRef(Component)
    React.ForwardRefRenderFunction<HTMLButtonElement, {
        label: string,
        checked: boolean,
        onBlur: React.FocusEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>
    }> = ({label, ...rest}) => {
    // Spreading ...rest here will pass the ref :)
    return <FormControlLabel control={<Switch {...rest} />}
        labelPlacement={"top"}
        label={label}
    />;
};

// *Huzzah!*
export default React.forwardRef(TradingStrategyEditFormInstructionsInputSwitch);
```

CustomSwitchController.tsx

```
<Controller
    control={formCtx.control}
    name={fieldPath}
    key={type + side + key}
    render={({field}) => {
        return <TradingStrategyEditFormInstructionsInputField
            {...field}
            label={key}
            checked={field.value}
            onBlur={() => {
                field.onBlur()
                handleOnBlur(key)
            }}
        />
    }}/>
```

Idk if we're allowed to link YT Videos, but techsith has a great video on using forwardRef with useRef that should clear things up.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScT4ElKd6eo

Answer (score -1):

Your input component does not export ref as props since it is a functional component.

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    register('name', { required: true });
  }, []);

         <InputFloatLabel
            type="text"
            placeholder="Name"
            name="name"
           // Remove the register from here
          />
```

Comment: Actually valid answer.