# Not a duplicate - React Warning: Function components cannot be given refs

Tags: reactjs

I am building a react project using react hooks and arrow functions for my component
I have a couple of Phone Inputs using react-phone-input-2
However once I compile my code I am getting the error

```
Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
```

I have been searching and browsing for hours now and cannot waste any more time on it
this is my code:

```
            <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div className="form-group">
              <div className="label">Work No.</div>
              <Controller
                {...register("workNumber")}
                control={control}
                rules={{ required: true }}
                render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
                  <PhoneInput
                    value={value}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    country={"us"}
                    disabled={!active}
                  />
                )}
              />
              {errors["workNumber"] && (
                <p className="required_txt">This field is required</p>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div className="form-group">
              <div className="label">Fax No.</div>
              <Controller
                {...register("workNumber")}
                control={control}
                rules={{ required: true }}
                render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
                  <PhoneInput
                    value={value}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    country={"us"}
                    disabled={!active}
                  />
                )}
              />
              {errors["FaxNumber"] && (
                <p className="required_txt">This field is required</p>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

These are part of a larger form being populated through react form and reset functions from an API axios request
Can someone please explain why I am getting a ref error even though I cannot see where I have referenced any of my inputs and how to solve them?
Much appreciated
Regards

Comment: [This wasn't any help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67877887/react-hook-form-v7-function-components-cannot-be-given-refs-attempts-to-access)? Or [this](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/85)?

Comment: You have no idea for how long I have wasted so many hours...I guess i just need some sleep... Thank you lots 
Maybe add it an answer or could a moderator close this question if it is seen as a duplicate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React hook form v7 Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67877887/react-hook-form-v7-function-components-cannot-be-given-refs-attempts-to-access)

Comment: yes that is corrent