# React-hook-form - Function components cannot be given refs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

When trying to create a reusable input component that accepts a register react-hook-form Register function I get the error:

`Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()`

Following that, and solutions similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68927377/5258150) I ended up with [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-firefly-n70quh?file=/src/SelectInput.tsx), however as you can see when clicking submit the values don't seem to get updated on the form.

I assumed this might've been because react-hook-form's internal ref is different from the one being forwarded, but looking at [the docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register) it doesn't seem like there's a way to pass a ref.

Seeing how [react-number-format](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-firefly-n70quh?file=/src/PatternInput.tsx) binds well using a Controller I also tried that, but it still doesn't seem to work.

How would I go about creating this reusable component that can bind to different forms?

Comment: This is how much I could fix
https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-cache-sen6ll?file=/src/TextInput.tsx
you might want the ControlInput to have a controlled Input with a useState to hande the warnings

Answer (score 1):

In your `App.tsx` file, change `TextInput` props as below.

```
<TextInput
    placeholder="Text Input"
    errors={errors.testInput}
    register={register}
    name={"testInput"}
    options={ { required: true }}
    // {...register("testInput", { required: true })} Don't destructure register here
  />
```

If `register` is destructured, then `ref` is passed directly to `TextInput` which is a function component and thus error in console.

`register` docs: https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register

No need to use `Controller` for native components. But in your code for `ControlInput` to work, pass `onChange` from `field` to input's `onChange` attribute.

```
render={({ field: { onChange, name, value } }) => (
      <input
        id={name}
        // name={name}
        type={fieldType}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        value={value||''}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    )}
```