# Textarea input fields in Chakra UI wont submit to react hook form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, chakra-ui

I am using nextjs (v13), react (v18) chakraUI and react hook form.

If I use Inputs (only), I can submit this form. If I change the description field to be a Textarea (from ChakraUI), the form displays on the page, but will not submit. I get no errors in the console - I can't see what's causing the issue.

Is it possible to submit data from a Textarea via react-hook-form?

```
import * as React from "react"
import { gql } from "@apollo/client"
import { Button, Stack, Textarea, Text } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import { useRouter } from "next/router"

import { useCreateIssueGroupMutation } from "lib/graphql"
import { useForm } from "lib/hooks/useForm"
import Yup from "lib/yup"

import { ButtonGroup } from "./ButtonGroup"
import { Form } from "./Form"
import { FormError } from "./FormError"
import { Input } from "./Input"
import { Modal } from "antd"

const _ = gql`
  mutation CreateIssueGroup($data: IssueGroupInput!) {
    createIssueGroup(data: $data) {
      id
    }
  }
`

interface Props {
  onClose: () => void
}

const IssueGroupSchema = Yup.object().shape({
 
  title: Yup.string().required(),
  description: Yup.string().required(),
})

export function AdminCreateIssueGroupForm(props: Props) {
  const router = useRouter()
  const [createIssueGroup] = useCreateIssueGroupMutation()
  const defaultValues = {
    
    title: "",
    description: "",
  }
  const form = useForm({ defaultValues, schema: IssueGroupSchema })
  const handleSubmit = (data: Yup.InferType<typeof IssueGroupSchema>) => {
    return form.handler(() => createIssueGroup({ variables: { data: { ...data } } }), {
      onSuccess: (res, toast) => {
        
        toast({ description: "Issue group created" })
        form.reset()
        props.onClose()
        
      },
    })
  }
  return (
    <Form {...form} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Stack>
        <Input name="title" label="Title" />
       // this input works and allows me to submit the form
        {/* <Input name="description" label="Description" /> */}
       // the next 2 lines do not work. The page renders but the form does not submit  
        <Text mb='8px' fontWeight="medium" fontSize="sm" > Description</Text>
        <Textarea name="description" rows={4} />
       
        <FormError />
        <ButtonGroup>
          <Button onClick={props.onClose}>Cancel</Button>
          <Button
           
            type="submit"
            isLoading={form.formState.isSubmitting}
            isDisabled={form.formState.isSubmitting}
            color="brand.white"
            fontWeight="normal"
            backgroundColor="brand.orange"
            
            _hover={{
              backgroundColor: "brand.green",
              color: "brand.white",
            }}
          >
            Create
          </Button>
        </ButtonGroup>
      </Stack>
    </Form>
  )
}
```

My Form component has:

```
import * as React from "react"
import type { FieldValues, UseFormReturn } from "react-hook-form"
import { FormProvider, useFormContext } from "react-hook-form"
import { Box } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/nextjs"

import { useToast } from "lib/hooks/useToast"

interface FormContainerProps {
  onSubmit?: (values: any) => Promise<any> | any
  onBlur?: (values: any) => Promise<any> | any
}

const FormContainer: React.FC<FormContainerProps> = (props) => {
  const toast = useToast()
  const { handleSubmit } = useFormContext()
  const onSubmit = async (values: any) => {
    try {
      if (props.onBlur) {
        return await props.onBlur(values)
      }
      if (props.onSubmit) {
        return await props.onSubmit(values)
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
      Sentry.captureException(e)
      toast({
        title: "Application error",
        description: "Something went wrong. We have been notified!",
        status: "error",
      })
      return
    }
  }

  return (
    <Box
      as="form"
      w="100%"
      {...(props.onSubmit && { onSubmit: handleSubmit(onSubmit) })}
      {...(props.onBlur && { onBlur: handleSubmit(onSubmit) })}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Box>
  )
}

interface Props<T extends FieldValues> extends UseFormReturn<T>, FormContainerProps {
  children: React.ReactNode
  isDisabled?: boolean
}

export function Form<T extends FieldValues>({ onSubmit, onBlur, isDisabled, ...props }: Props<T>) {
  return (
    <FormProvider {...props}>
      <fieldset disabled={isDisabled}>
        <FormContainer {...{ onSubmit, onBlur }}>{props.children}</FormContainer>
      </fieldset>
    </FormProvider>
  )
}
```

Input has:

```
import * as React from "react"
import { useFormContext } from "react-hook-form"
import type { InputProps } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { FormControl, Input as CInput } from "@chakra-ui/react"

import { InputError } from "./InputError"
import { InputLabel } from "./InputLabel"

interface Props extends InputProps {
  name: string
  label?: string
  subLabel?: string
}

export const Input = ({ label, subLabel, ...props }: Props) => {
  const {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useFormContext()
  const fieldError = errors?.[props.name]
  return (
    <FormControl isInvalid={!!fieldError} isRequired={props.isRequired}>
      <InputLabel label={label} subLabel={subLabel} name={props.name} />
      <CInput {...register(props.name)} mb={0} {...props} />
      <InputError error={fieldError} />
    </FormControl>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Each form component connected to React Hook Form needs to receive a `register` or be wrapped by a `Controller` component. Your input component receives this by `useFormContext` as you mentioned:

```
<CInput {...register(props.name)} mb={0} {...props} />
```

However, `TextArea` component doesn't receive anything from Hook Form, in that case, you need to use the same `register('')`.

An example of this implementation ([live on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/chakraui-rhf-40x9gf?file=/src/index.tsx)):

```
function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      title: "",
      description: ""
    }
  });

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => console.log(data))}>
        <Heading>Welcome to Chakra + TS</Heading>

        <p>Title</p>
        <Input {...register("title")} />

        <p>Description</p>
        <Textarea {...register("description")} />
        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Useful links:

- [Register](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register)
- [Controller](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller)
- [Live Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/chakraui-rhf-40x9gf?file=/src/index.tsx)

Comment: Thank you- it sounds sensible and logical. There must be another step. When I try this, I get an error that says Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
I'll have to read these docs more carefully to try and find the gap between what you've been able to demonstrate and what I am trying to do. I'll come back tomorrow to let you know. Thank you for this.

Comment: I think part of the answer might be in this post but it's too complicated for me to understand on first read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67877887/react-hook-form-v7-function-components-cannot-be-given-refs-attempts-to-access

Comment: In this case, I used directly the `Input` component from ChakraUI, in your case you don't need to pass a `register` because you have a custom Input component structure to get it with `useFormContext`. You end up connecting all elements to react-hook-form.  An example using your Input component: https://codesandbox.io/s/chakraui-rhf-custom-input-component-n08w6m?file=/src/index.tsx
If you really want to pass a `register` for all elements at the top level (I don't think it's really necessary) in a custom component you will need to work with `fowardRef`.

Comment: I tried removing register from title and just using it with description (which is I think what you are suggesting), but it doesnt work

Comment: Can you provide a detailed error message or a Codesandbox link with your implementation? It will be really useful to help you.

Comment: It's okay, I used Input.tsx to make a Textarea and have it working now. Thank you for sharing your work